# Regular expression challenge to match same numbers separately

Tags: regex

I am struggling with a nice challenge to match two same numbers separately, with a regex.

See here the list I am trying to match separately.

```
1,680,000,0001,680,000,000
3,350,0003,350,000
110,000110,000
11,100,00011,100,000
550,000550,000
1,0001,000
250250
49,50049,500
165,000165,000
49,50049,500
3,350,0003,350,000
165,000165,000
550,000550,000
550,000550,000
33,10033,100
18,10018,100
450,000450,000
```

Take for example 550,000550,000, that's twice 550,000 or 250250 that's twice 250. I want to match for example 550,000 and 250.

I have tested many regular expressions in RegexBuddy, but no one does what I want. Maybe you have a suggestion?

Comment: So if you want to match 6 numbers do `\d{6}`? Might misunderstood you.

Comment: What flavour of regex are you using? Javascript? Java? .NET? Each has their own limitations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, then

```
^(.+)\1$
```

should work. You can restrict the possible matches to only allow digits and commas like this:

```
^([\d,]+)\1$
```

This matches a "double number" and keeps the first repetition in capturing group number 1. If you want your match only to contain the first repetition, then use

```
^([\d,]+)(?=\1$)
```

[image: RegexBuddy screenshot]

Comment: I added all three in my RegexBuddy program, but none matches?

Comment: @DelphiLynx: Did you set the "^/$ match start/end of line" option?

Comment: Thank you, I had to set "Match at line breaks"  an that did it. Question answered.